# Available width inside algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, width

I wanted to use an environment inside an `algorithm2e` and it turned out, that it is too wide. I tried to draw some boxes to see the width, and it turned out that `\textwidth` is too large inside the algorithm. The `framed` environment however adheres to the correct size.

**My question is:** How can I access the available width in the algorithm area?

[image: An example using a <code>frames</code> environment, which works fine and a box of width <code>\textwidth</code>, which is too large.]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{framed}
      something in a framed environment
    \end{framed}
    \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{
      something with textwidth
    }}
    \caption{Some algorithm.}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that `framed` can't do for you?

Comment: I used an enumerate environment and that was exceeding the available space for long lines. However, there should not be a frame around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `algorithm` environment increases left and right margins of its contents, so you have to substract them from `textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{framed}
      something in a framed environment
    \end{framed}
Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text…Some text… Some text… Some text… Some text… \\[1ex]
    \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}{something with textwidth }}\\[1ex]

    \caption{Some algorithm.}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, the implementation of framed does the same? That would imply the author of framed implemented specific solutions for other packages which I think might be a lot of work!

Comment: Or more probably the author of `algorithm2e` implemented his layout in a way that tickles standard TeX/LaTeX internal lengths, and `framed` uses these standard lengths. After all, `\algomargin` is just a `local leftskip`-`\rightskip` made equal.